# Custom VX680 applications

Tags: point-of-sale, verifone

I just bought an used Verifone VX680. This terminal used to run a custom application for a movie theater or something like that. They removed the software and cleaned up the terminal.

I need to develop an application for a delivery management system, nothing very serious yet.

After some time of research, I found that I have 3 ways to get this done:
1. Pay for some company to develop the system.
2. Pay (huge ammounts, relatively) for a framework and their services.
3. Get certified by Verifone to get access on the documentation and IDE, so I can develop my own application.

The third one seems to be the more sustainable, because I would develop my own application, in my terms. Besides the knowledge that I would acquire.

But I cannot find any information about this training. Only an email at the Verifone website that I cannot get any reply.

I'm aware that the application needs to be written in C++, it needs a specific IDE, a specific SDK and require a certificate to sign the files. But that's it.

I do not know anything else besides that and don't know how to get this info.

There's someone that already has done that and could tell me more about, or at least where I can get this info?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You are mostly correct:

> I'm aware that the application needs to be written in C++, it needs a specific IDE, a specific SDK and require a certificate to sign the files.

You do write it in C++, but you don't need any specific IDE. I happen to use Visual Studio, but Notepad should also work fine. You *DO* need a license to compile for the ARM processor, and that's not cheap. After you get certified, the SDK is free, but certification is also a bit pricey if you are paying out of your own pocket. The signing cards used to be pretty cheap, but they were something like $200 a piece, last I checked.
That leads me to another point - the used terminal MUST not have another certificate installed on it, or you won't be able to use it. When the previous owners cleaned it up, if they didn't remove the certificate, it is of no value to you. If they did, or if you can take it back and have them do it for you after the fact, you're fine.

If you are still interested in learning more, go to Verifone's DevNet

http://www.verifonedevnet.com/verifone/devnet/dnProgramView.do?channelId=-9088&programId=122369&programPage=/jsp/devnet/program/dnDevTrain.jsp&pageTypeId=109139

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply, this is a very blurry area for me. So let me see if I get it right, I will need to get certified by Verifone and get the ARM license? Or those are two different paths? If possible, would you mind telling me about how much I would spend on certification?

Comment: I don't remember the costs--my company paid for it; I just remember that I was glad it wasn't coming from MY pocket!  You need the ARM compiler license regardless.  The training gets you up and going, but more importantly, it gives you access to their DevNet site which has all the downloads you'll need (like the SDK) to get going.  You can probably get access without the class, but I don't know how much that would save you, if anything.